# Installing/deleting root certificate without CertMgr / CertUtil asking the end-user for confirmation

Tags: certificate, certutil

When you install or delete a root CA certificate using the commandline tools [CertUtil.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732443(WS.10).aspx) or [CertMgr.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78byta0(VS.80).aspx), Windows asks the user for confirmation using a MessageBox (for certificates other than root CA ones, this question is not asked), even for the root CA certificate store for the current user.

For unattended certificate updates, that is a hassle.

I have seen this behaviour on Windows XP, Vista and 7 (I have not checked Windows Server 2003 and 2008 yet, but I assume they ask this question as well).

I have two questions:

1. Why is Windows asking that question, even when you install/delete it from a command-line tool?
2. How can I suppress this (other than observing the dialog boxes coming up and sending Windows messages to press the "Yes" button)?

The MessageBox confirmation dialogs look like this:

```
[Root Certificate Store]
Do you want to DELETE the following certificate from the Root Store?
...
[&Yes]  [&No]
```

and this:

```
[Security Warning]
You are about to install a certificate from a certification authority (CA) claiming to represent:
...
[&Yes]  [&No]
```

--jeroen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest solution is to incorporate the answer in the script like this:

```
echo Y | CertUtil.exe ....
```

This method doesn't always work for all programs, so it still needs some testing on your side.

For message-boxes, you can use [nircmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) with the `dlg` parameter.
In a script, you may also use the built-in command `timeout /t seconds` to give the message box the specified number of seconds in which to appear.

Here is an extract of the help file:

> `nircmd.exe dlg [Process Name] [Window Title] [Action] [Parameters]`
>
> Allows you to interact with standard
>   dialog-boxes and message-boxes of
>   Windows. When a dialog-box is opened,
>   you can use this command to "click"
>   the ok/cancel/yes/no buttons, or fill
>   the text-boxes in the dialog-box.
>
> The following command will choose the
>   'Yes' answer for any question
>   dialog-box of Explorer process:
>   `dlg "explorer.exe" "" click yes`
>
> The following command will choose the
>   'Cancel' answer for any question
>   dialog-box of any process:
>   `dlg "" "" click cancel`
>
> Parameters description:
>
> [Process Name]: Specifies the process
>   that created the desired window. You
>   can specify only the process name or
>   the full path of the process. If this
>   parameter is empty string("" ), the
>   command will be executed on any
>   process.
>
> [Window Title]: Specifies the title of
>   the window that you want the execute
>   the action. If this parameter is empty
>   string("" ), the command will be
>   executed on any window, regardless the
>   window title.
>
> [Action]: You can specify one of the
>   following options:
>   click: Click the
>   specified button. You can specify one
>   of the following predefined values
>   (For standard Windows dialog-boxes
>   only !): yes, no, ok, cancel, retry,
>   ignore, close, help. You can also
>   specify any control ID as numeric
>   value.
>   settext: Set the text of the
>   specified control. The first parameter
>   of this action specifies the ID of the
>   control, and the second parameter
>   specifies the text.

Comment: This doesn't work on the messageboxes that Windows uses to ask for confirmation. (I have edited my question to make the use of MessageBoxes by Windows more clearly).

Comment: @Jeroen Pluimers: OK - added.

Comment: Thx! It is similar to what I came up myself.

Answer (score 1):

For those cases such as removing a trusted root certificate from the user store, that does not require any non-native software, I resort to removing the certificate out of the registry with reg delete.  Note the X's below represent the thumbprint of the certificate.

`reg delete HKCU\Software\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\Root\Certificates\XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX /f`

Answer (score 0):

For someone who, like me, was looking for how to respond with "yes" to the certutil.exe window via nircmd, follow command.

`C:\Users\<user>\Desktop>nircmdc.exe dlg "certutil.exe" "" click yes execmd certutil.exe -p xxxxx -user -importpfx cert.p12`